# How can I remove all variables that do not have multiple distinct observations in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with several variables that have only one unique observation (e.g. the variable *Language* is equal to "English" for every observation in the dataset).  I attempted to write a function that automatically finds any variable of this nature and removes it from the dataframe.  The following code works, but I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing this.  Any ideas?

```
test.df <- data.frame(var1=rep("a",5), var2=c(rep("a",3),rep("b",2)),
                      var3=1:5, var4=rep(0,5)) 

remove.repeat.vars <- function(data) {
  one.level.factors <- sapply(data, function(x) ifelse(length(unique(x)) < 2, 1, 0))
  one.level.factors <- names(one.level.factors[which(one.level.factors == 1)])
  return (data[,-which(names(data) %in% one.level.factors)])
}

 remove.repeat.vars(test.df)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One liner:

```
test.df[, sapply(test.df, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1)]
```

Here is why it works. R supports two different ways to index a vector: with vector of indexes (of any length) or with a boolean vector. Compare:

```
> x <- 6:10
> x[c(1,3,5)]
[1]  6  8 10
> x[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]
[1] 6 9
```

The second one is why things like `x[x>7]` work.

Comment: awesome. so the sapply spits out a logical vector and you use the subsetting brackets to select only the columns for which the logical is "TRUE". I tried something a lot like this and couldn't get it to work, but now that it's right in front of me I can't believe I needed help with this.

Comment: +1 nice answer.  However, the explanation is not altogether accurate. `R` supports multiple ways of indexing, and boolean vectors do not need to be of the same length.  Standard recycling rules apply ;)    eg: get all odd values up to N:  `seq(N)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]`